# getting error while inserting values into table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, timestamp

Table structure is

```
Name          Null Type         
------------- ---- ------------ 
T_NO               NUMBER       
T_NAME             VARCHAR2(10) 
ENTERING_TIME      TIMESTAMP(6) 
LEAVING_TIME       TIMESTAMP(6) 
TO_DATE            DATE
```

Trigger

```
create or replace trigger t4
before insert
on t4
for each row
declare
d_entering_time timestamp(6):=to_char('09:00:00AM','HH12:MM:SSAM');
begin
if (:new.entering_time <= d_entering_time)  then
raise_application_error
(-20002,'Date of joining cannot be after system date.');
end if;
end;
```

and my inserting query

```
insert INTO t3 (entering_time) values ( TO_date('8:31:51AM','HH:MI:SSAM'))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.T3", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.T3'
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Can any one suggest me where error occuring?

Comment: `to_char()` converts a date (or timestamp) into a string literal. You want `to_timestamp()` instead. Are you aware of the fact that a timestamp also includes a date part?

Comment: even if use  'to_timestamp()' am getting same error

Comment: Do you understand what an Oracle timestamp is? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#autoId14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T4
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON T3
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    SSSSS_ENTERING_TIME NUMBER := 32400;
BEGIN
    IF ( TO_NUMBER ( TO_CHAR ( :NEW.ENTERING_TIME,
                          'SSSSS' ) ) <= SSSSS_ENTERING_TIME )
    THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (
                             -20002,
                             'Date of joining cannot be after system date.' );
    END IF;
END;

INSERT INTO
      T3 ( ENTERING_TIME )
VALUES
      ( TO_TIMESTAMP ( '01/01/2010 8:31:51AM',
                    'DD/MM/RR HH:MI:SSAM.FF' ) );
```

Note: I have extracted the total seconds from the time part and converted to a number for comparing. Hence I used 32400 seconds which is nothing but the actual 9 AM.

In Oracle we can turn dates into numbers and apply arithmetic to them in a variety of ways.

Hence `to_char(some_date, 'SSSSS')` gives us its time element as the number of seconds since midnight.

Comment: ok then how to inset values in to values(i mean in which formate )

Comment: No change in inserts.. This is just a check. You can do the normal way. INSERT INTO
   T3 ( ENTERING_TIME )
VALUES
   ( TO_TIMESTAMP ( '01/01/2010 8:31:51AM',
        'DD/MM/RR HH:MI:SSAM.FF' ) );

Comment: I do not see any problem. Post your insert statement with error

Comment: hello it showing error can u show me what trying in #SQL fiddle

Comment: If you are facing a problem. then you setup in SQL fiddle and show me what is the issue. I tested the script before posting and works well.

Comment: INSERT INTO
      T3 ( ENTERING_TIME )
VALUES
      ( TO_TIMESTAMP ( '01/01/2010 8:31:51AM',
                    'DD/MM/RR HH:MI:SSAM.FF' ) )
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-20002: Date of joining cannot be after system date.
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.T4", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.T4'

Comment: This is the correct error. time is 8:31 AM so it should fail. this is what you asked for. Try to insert with greater time value.

Comment: @user2801653, it's your application error, that time is less than 09:00Am.

Comment: ya i got result thanq.ya u r right now me also inserting values into sql tables

Comment: @realspirituals, you have done it well, thanks for pointing out the issues.

Comment: @realspirituals  if i trying to insert exact 9:00:00Am it showing error why?                                             INSERT INTO
      T3 ( ENTERING_TIME )
VALUES
      ( TO_TIMESTAMP ( '01/01/2010 9:00:00AM',
                    'DD/MM/RR HH:MI:SSAM.FF' ) )
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-20002: Date of joining cannot be after system date.
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.T4", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.T4'

Comment: @Dba if i trying to insert exact 9:00:00Am it showing error why? INSERT INTO T3 ( ENTERING_TIME ) VALUES ( TO_TIMESTAMP ( '01/01/2010 9:00:00AM', 'DD/MM/RR HH:MI:SSAM.FF' ) ) Error report: SQL Error: ORA-20002: Date of joining cannot be after system date. ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.T4", line 7 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.T4'

Comment: @user2801653 as I said 09:00:00 is 32400. so in your original requirement you asked for if (:new.entering_time <= d_entering_time) Hence you get the error. Working fine as per OP's initial requriement

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is some errors in your code,

- You are trying to store a string literal into to timestamp variable.

> `d_entering_time timestamp(6):=to_char('09:00:00AM','HH12:MM:SSAM');`

- It's `HH12:MI:SSAM`, not `HH12:MM:SSAM`, `MI` is for minute and `MM` is for month.

You can try like this,

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t4 
    BEFORE INSERT ON t3 FOR EACH ROW 
    DECLARE 
         d_entering_time TIMESTAMP :=to_timestamp('09:00:00AM','HH12:MI:SSAM.FF');
    BEGIN
         IF (:NEW.entering_time <= d_entering_time) THEN
              raise_application_error (-20002,'Date of joining cannot be after system date.');
         END IF;
    END;
```

Insert query,

```
   INSERT INTO t3 (entering_time) VALUES ( to_timestamp('8:31:51AM','HH:MI:SSAM.FF'));
```

Comment: This will not work if you try this:       INSERT INTO t3 (entering_time) VALUES ( to_timestamp('01/01/2010 9:31:51AM','DD/MM/RR HH:MI:SSAM.FF'));

Comment: @DBA thanq i got my expecting result thanq for helping and ur valuble advices...thanq.._^_

Comment: @user2801653 INSERT INTO t3 (entering_time) VALUES ( to_timestamp('01/01/2010 9:31:51AM','DD/MM/RR HH:MI:SSAM.FF')); 
  
ORA-20002: Date of joining cannot be after system date.
ORA-06512: at "T4", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'T4'

Comment: Wait. I am trying the same

Comment: @user2801653, actually what is the real purpose of storing the time part only in timestamp field.?

Comment: my purpose if u enter less than 9.00.00am then entering value stored in table or else it shows error.that my purpose i wrote this program in pl sql trigger

Comment: So there is no importance of checking date there, rite?

Comment: ya noo need date here

Comment: @Dba if i trying to insert exact 9:00:00Am it showing error why? INSERT INTO T3 ( ENTERING_TIME ) VALUES ( TO_TIMESTAMP ( '01/01/2010 9:00:00AM', 'DD/MM/RR HH:MI:SSAM.FF' ) ) Error report: SQL Error: ORA-20002: Date of joining cannot be after system date. ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.T4", line 7 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.T4'

Comment: @user2801653, The trigger will throw exception if the time is <= `09:00AM`. If you want to insert the time if it is `09:00AM`, then try to modify the trigger like `IF( TO_NUMBER ( TO_CHAR ( :NEW.ENTERING_TIME, 'SSSSS' ) ) < SSSSS_ENTERING_TIME ) THEN`.

Comment: in my query clearly i mentioned na "Less than or equal to" then y we need to that